# Excel file records validations using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, excel, laravel-5, jquery-validate

I'm doing excel file uploading and saving it in database using laravel. Here i want to validate excel file columns means i have 5 columns in excel file like provider_id, cpt_code, reimbursementrate, billedamount and dueamount.

If anyone upload file with only 4 columns i have to return false before submitting. How can i do this can anyone help me in this?

I have tried this code:

```
$("#form").validate({
    rules: {
        file: {
            required: true,
            extension: "xlsx|xls|xlsm"
        }
    },
   messages:{
     file: {
        required: "file .xlsx, .xlsm, .xls only.",
        extension: "Please upload valid file formats .xlsx, .xlsm, .xls only."
     }
   }

});

$("#submit").click(function() {
    var file = $('#file').val();

    if($("#create_form").valid()) {
        if(file != '') {
           // do something
        }
    }
});
```

and laravel validation :

```
  $validation = array(
            'provider_id'=>'required',
            'file'=>'required',                
        );
```

Comment: you've only posted JS code but the Excel validation is done in PHP. I'd recommend the [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) library for this

Comment: I have done laravel validation, is there any method like phpexcel in laravel?

Comment: I don't know Laravel well enough, but you'll most likely need to do the validation manually - open the file with PHPExcel, then count the number of columns in the first sheet.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense... looking inside the file has nothing to do with jQuery Validate... you'll have to rely on server-side code.